Timelike normal vector becomes null
I have a metric given by
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = \frac{e^{2 A(z)}}{z^2} \left(-g(z) dt^2 + \frac{dz^2}{g(z)} + dx^2 + dx^2_1 + dx^2_2 \right)
\end{equation}
where $A(z) = -a \ln(b z^2 + 1)$ and $g(z)$ is the blackening factor. This metric is setup in $AdS_5$ and the boundary $z=0$ conditions are that $A(0) = 0$ and $g(0) = 1$.
I have calculated the Ricci scalar $R^{(5)}$ of the bulk $AdS_5$ and although it is dependent on $z$, it is finite even when $z=0$, which is expected.
I want to introduce a hypersurface (also known as a brane) given by the equation $\Phi=t-x$, and a rough sketch is shown below. Note that the image may not represent what is actually the behavior of the brane since you have to consider the embedding process, as for $z\neq 0$ it is timelike, but for $z=0$ it is null. See the normal vector below.

I have calculated the brane/hypersurface Ricci scalar $R^{(4)}$ using $R^{(4)} = h^{ab} R^{(4)}_{ab}$ where $h_{ab}$ is the induced metric given by,
\begin{equation}
ds^2_{ind} = \frac{e^{2 A(z)}}{z^2} \left((1-g(z)) dt^2 + \frac{dz^2}{g(z)} + dx^2_1 + dx^2_2 \right)
\end{equation}
However,
\begin{equation}
R^{(4)} \sim \frac{1}{(-1 + g(z))^2} \qquad \textrm{*there's some z dependent terms on top but it's not relevant here}
\end{equation}
which diverges at $z=0$ since $g(z) \rightarrow 1$ as $z \rightarrow 0$.
I have also tried to calculate $R^{(4)}$ for the brane $\Phi=x-x_0$ (which is timelike everywhere), and $R^{(4)}$ is finite everywhere.
So, here's what I did. The brane $\Phi=t-x$ has a normal vector (normalized) given by,
\begin{equation}
n_\mu = \sqrt{\frac{e^{2 A(z)} g(z)}{z^2 (-1+g(z))}} (1,0,-1,0,0)
\end{equation}
that satisfies $n_\mu n^\mu = 1$ which indicates that it is timelike for $z\neq 0$. However, obviously at $z=0$, it is null. I believe that the divergence is due to this jump from timelike to null.
I have read some papers, for example 1609.00207, that discusses null boundary terms that should be added to the Einstein-Hilbert action instead of the typical GHY boundary term which applies only to timelike/spacelike boundaries. However, in my case, the boundary (brane) is timelike, although the boundary of this timelike brane is null. I believe this null segment should be treated as a corner term instead. On the other hand, these just talk about what terms to include in the action in order for the variational principle to be well defined. My issue here is that the brane Ricci scalar $R^{(4)}$ diverges so I believe some renormalization must be done instead.
Any guidance/comments on what to do?
